# What are the most widely comic books formats?

Tags: formatting, comics

What are the most widely comic books formats? Let's say you want to publish online comics across multiple platforms such as Amazon and modern digital platforms. What standards should you use if you don't want to change the format and want to use a single one across several different platforms? By format, I mean image size (800x600) and type (png, jpg).

Comment: What does "format" mean here? PNG vs JPEG? Traditional grid layout vs infinite scroll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a crawler to analyze around 20000 webcomics listed on http://www.thewebcomiclist.com

**Disclaimer.**
Take these results with caution: the crawler made guesses as to what constitutes the main webcomic content instead of, for instance, a website banners. Files of types not strictly meant as image file types were not processed, e.g. PDFs.

In any event, these are the results:

Image size:

```
       width  height
mean     491     429
std      455     587
25%      100      40
50%      449     238
75%      748     656
```

File type:

```
.jpg     46%
.gif     29%
.png     15%
other    10%
```

Note that there are at least three to four popular aspect ratios (here computed as height over width). From manual inspection on a very small sample size:

- the larger, e.g. the peak at 1.5 are likely webcomics that have an overarching story;
- the smaller ones (e.g. the peak around 0.3) are single strips

[image: Density of aspect ratios]

Another way to look at aspect ratios is to plot the contours, with a bit of jitter. The axes are in pixels. You can easily identify the long panels with high aspect ratio, the flat and wide panels and the square ones at the intersection with an emergent shape at 600 x 600.

[image: overlay of image sizes]

Comment: Can you make a histogram of the size data, or a scatter plot? Because I think averages and standard deviation says very little in this case. It probably clusters around a couple of distinct sizes. A graph of aspect ratio might also be worthwhile.

Comment: Aspect ratio is probably more useful than raw image size, because you want to get a large image size (high DPI) and that will let you scale down if necessary, but it's a lot harder to change the aspect ratio. It's definitely worth seeing what are the standard sizes/ratios, rather than taking an average which might be an awkward compromise.

Comment: While this is an interesting approach, it doesn't give the information OP really needs, for one reason: some sites *only* support one format. For example, ComiXology seems to only support PDF (yes, not even an image format).

Comment: Instead of averaging, can you tell me what the most common format is?

Comment: did some improvements to the crawler and recomputing... stay tuned

Comment: @Sayaman now with histograms and pictures

Comment: @Laurel added a comment about PDFs

Comment: Really nice, but I am wondering about the ones published on Amazon though.

Comment: @Sayaman Do you mean e-books and printed comic-books on amazon? Or do they do webcomics now as well?
--
NB. I checked some of the webcomics on my daily reading list, and the first 25 didn't have a single size in common. Also no exact ratio match (but a large cluster around the 1.5 ratio)